# what is the difference between the & and : in PL/SQL in oracle?

Tags: sql, plsql, sqldatatypes

I am stuying PL/SQL & I am going through the bind variable .
I understood that the bind variable we used to pass RUN-TIME values.

but what is the difference between & and :(colon) in PL/SQL? both are same or is their any difference between this two? when should I use & and : ?

Answer (score 12):

The `&` is used in `SQL*Plus` only, it has no meaning outside of it.

While `SQL*Plus` "parses" the input buffer, it replaces `&variables` with what they were `define`d to. See also [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm#SQPUG037) and [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref453). The *technical term* is *substitution variable*.

On the other hand `:variable` are *real* bind variables. They are used when Oracle's SQL engine "parses" and executes the SQL statement. See for example [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/glossary.htm#CNCPT44447) or [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref522).

So, in short, `&variables` are replaced by SQL*Plus and *then* passed to Oracle's SQL engine, while `:variables` are left untouched by SQL*Plus and passed to Oracle's SQL engine as they appear. Outside fo SQL*Plus, `&` makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

`&` has no meaning in PL/SQL, it is actually a SQL Plus feature (that has been copied in Toad, SQL Developer etc. for compatibility).  In SQL Plus, `&` is used to define a **substitution variable**, which is replaced with specified replacement text by SQL Plus before the code is sent to the server to be processed.

The correct syntax for a SQL Plus substitution variable is `&name.` i.e. is begins with a `&` and ends with a `.`, but in most situations the `.` is optional.  So when you run this code in SQL Plus:

```
select * from emp where ename = '&name.';
```

SQL Plus prompts the user for a value for `name` and substitues this into the query **before** it is run.  So if the user enters `KING` then the SQL actually run is:

```
select * from emp where ename = 'KING';
```

Comment: what about more than one value? I tried
`select * from emp where ename IN ('&name*.');`

Comment: You could write `select * from emp where ename IN (&name.);` (note: no quotes around `&name,` and no *, whatever that was for) then when prompted for `name` enter data with quotes: 'KING', 'SCOTT', 'WILSON'.  That literally gets substituted to become: `select * from emp where ename IN ('KING', 'SCOTT', 'WILSON');`