# Exception handling in Pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
declare
x1 number;
y1 number;

begin
x1:=&x1_value;
y1:=&y2_value;
insert into tblnewdata_jk4 values(70,'July',x1,y1);
commit;

exception
when invalid_number then
dbms.output.put_line('err');

end;
/
```

I have tried to write an exception block which will validate whether the input entered by the user is number or not.But I am unable to do so.Can anyone help me this issue.

Comment: what error are you getting.Maybe its because of how you've written dbms output. it should be written like this `dbms_output.put_line('err')`;

Answer (score 3):

- > First, `dbms.output.put_line('err');` should be written like this `dbms_output.put_line('err')`
- > Secondly, `INVALID_NUMBER` for exception wont work unless you are converting a string to a number. You should use `VALUE_ERROR`
- > Lastly, Please avoid using `&` as a bind variable in pl sql, it has no meaning in pl sql because it is a feature in SQL*Plus. For more details, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172550/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-in-pl-sql-in-oracle)

Try this:

```
declare
x1 number;
y1 number;

begin
x1:=:x1_value;
y1:=:y2_value;
insert into tblnewdata_jk4 values(70,'July',x1,y1);
commit;

exception
when VALUE_ERROR then
dbms_output.put_line('err');

end;
/
```